# my project in production mode seems to process underscore Inline Templates

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, production-environment

I have a single page application and in my homepage.php I have this inline template:

```
<script class="layout" type="text/template">
  <header id="top-bar">
    <nav id="user-panel">
      <ul>
        <% if (logged === true) { %>
          <li><a class="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
          <li><a class="profile" href="/profile">Benvenuto <%= username %></a></li>
        <% } else { %>
          <li><a class="login" href="/login">Login</a></li>
          <li><a class="register" href="/register">Registrati gratis</a></li>
        <% }; %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <section id="mid-bar">
      <a id="logo" href="/"><img src=http://<?php echo $host; ?>/public/img/logo.png></a>
    </section>
    <div id="sub-view"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

As u can see on my user-panel nav i use the <% underscore %> notation, but if u inspect my source code on [my site](http://virtualmix.it/) it seems my web server or something i really dont know... process these tags...

I have also commented my underscore.js and my js code, but the problem persist...

Sorry for my bad english I hope you understand my issue!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing has something to do with backbone.

The error message is: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined**

This means that you are trying to apply the method extend to an undefined object.

It is difficult to understand what you want to do:
you should explain why are you using backbone, what you want to have.

To answet to your question: you should do some reverse engineering to find out which is the problem and which part of code is giving the problem.
It doesn't seem to be a php problem but rather a jquery problem, hence do the following:

1. put the `<script>` code AFTER the body tag
2. remove all the `<script>` includes
3. reload the page and see if it gives an error
4. add one by one the `<script>` includes (in a  proper order, e.g. do not include backbone before jquery) and see which is the one with the error.

Comment: Actually, if you *view source* on the website OP linked, it really looks like a server-side templating engine has already rendered his template tags out for him. Also I don't get JS errors on the page.

Comment: yes... maybe the servers supports ASP as well and try to interpret it as ASP code...